# Trace Routing / Noise Question

Tags: power, noise

I have a stackup like the following:

1. Top
2. GND
3. Power
4. Bottom

I am routing a trace that I have discovered is especially sensitive to noise; for example, when working with the signal on a bread board, the signal doesn't work properly if my jumper wire is too long (i.e., when connecting multiple thin ones together). Also, on a previous revision on this board I discovered that if the power supply is noisy, I can see problems, e.g., one of those cheap USB bricks you see at gas stations. This problem has somewhat resolved after running the power through a TPS62162DSGR (buck converter), which seems to clean the power up too.

To minimize the noise on this line I am wondering what, in general, is the best routing strategy for reducing noise on this line.

The destination pad is on the top. Currently I am routing it on the bottom layer and bring it up to the top layer with a via. This seems to work OK.

Can I improve on this design? The things I was thinking was:

1. Route it on the top layer (since GND) is right under it.
2. Increase trace width (to like 20mils)
3. Keep the trace as short as possible.

Are these ideas misguided? Any help/guidance/sage words would be greatly appreciated!

(Adding More Detail)

Ok, not to go all Sherlock Holmes, but I think I know what is going on here:

So the component in question here is a SK6812 5050, controlled over SPI. When I see the problem, the LED will flash wildly different colors. If I am connected to a power supply like a battery bank or my computer it's fine. Cheap USB bricks, I see the issue.

On an early version of the board, I designed the basic LED array as a header for a TI SimpleLink board (to retain the pin exposure and otherwise be able to debug easier.) I autorouted it just for times sake, and the routes came out like this in the area in question:

[image]

The signal comes IN on pin 4 and leaves on in 2.

To give some more detail, the way the TI board is designed, is that it passes 5V straight through, no power conversion. It uses a buck converter to create 3.3 for the MCU and other components. So any noise on that 5V line will be passed straight through.

What I *think* happens here is that 5V+ is too close to the data line. Hence the signal is getting corrupted.

I later revised the board, including my own MCU layout and so on and I manually routed the board. Now that area looks like this:

[image]

THIS version of the board doesn't display that problem. Even if it is connected to a cheap power brick. It's worth noting all power on this board is 3v3, and passed through the buck converter. The stackup on this board is as noted in the start of this post.

What other details would be helpful? Happy to add more.

In general, there are several of these led components chained together; they transmit the data line to each other. To catch it, I tapped one of my leads into the third one in the chain and I see this on the "noisy" one:

[image]

And I see this, on the properly functioning one.

[image]

Comment: Include a schematic, explain what that "noisy line" is used for. *the signal doesn't work properly* What signal, what does it do? How do you notice it doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Your 3 items are a great start.  To get any more detailed, we'd need to see the layout, and define what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: FYI for your stackup, I would route as much as possible on the top layer. This will reduce overall noise between adjacent signals and radiated noise.

Comment: I hope it's not TMI, but I added some more info, above @Aaron

Comment: I think you have done a pretty good job of solving your issue already. One thing though, if this is going to be more than just a hobby board, I would try to get that clock line on to one layer only, preferably the top layer for your stack up. At over 1Mhz that line will radiate much more due to going top to bottom and back again.